# Showing Time/Date Dialog within a Fragment getting GetSupportFragment() error

Tags: android, datepicker, datetimepicker, timepicker

Having issues with current code, utilizing googles guide for Time/Date picker fragment classes. The show method doesn't work. My error is in the show method.

newfragment.. (..getsupportfragmentmanager...) i don't have all the code atm writing this while on break at work so I don't forget.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Are you trying to launch a `TimePicker` ? The question is not clear,

Comment: Both a time picker, and date picker

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer for those who having the **getSupportFragmentManager()** error.

**CHANGE** that to...

**getFragmentManager()**

Then

Make sure your import shows this

**import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;**

You should be good to go!

You can now show a Time/Date Picker Dialog **WITHIN** a **FRAGMENT**.

**UPDATE** -- **EDIT**

This answer works great for fragments. I have since moved from using fragments for the greater purpose of my app. For those wanting to get this to work for Activities. I have been able to get this to simply work very easily.

This can work for both setting a date/time to **TextViews** or **Buttons**.

You can in any instance use the following to get a string after it has been passed to the TextView or Button in any activity. By applying **getActivity()** and then proceeded by:

```
YOURTEXTVIEW.getText().toString();
```

**OR**

```
YOURBUTTON.getText().toString();
```

Will set the proper **Date/Time** to your desired TextView or Button.

**DATEPICKER**

```
public class DatePicker extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    public static String TAG = DatePicker.class.getSimpleName();


    public Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();


    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);

    }


    @Override
    public void onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM, dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
                .format(new Date(year-1900,monthOfYear,dayOfMonth));
        Button rdb = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Request_Button_Date);
        rdb.setText(date);
    }
}
```

You will want to **subtract** 1900 from the **year** as in the above code to gather the proper int year value that is accurate.

**TimePicker**

```
public class TimePicker extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{

    public static String TAG = TimePicker.class.getSimpleName();


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));

    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Time t = new Time(hourOfDay,minute,0);//seconds by default set to zero
        Format formatter;
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String time = formatter.format(t);
        Button rtb = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Request_Button_Time);
        rtb.setText(time);
    }
}
```

notice how the context is **getActivity()**, and OnDateSetListener CallBack is **this**. That ensures the right context and callback is called for this. In my example I needed the callback to happen in this fragment.

There you go. You should be all set :)